# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no so in java.library.path

Tags: java, shared-libraries

```
When i'm trying to load the .so file from the Java, i'm getting error like this.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no yeslib.so in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at com.rct.micros.util.GetCustClass.getScratchCode(GetCustClass.java:76)
    at com.rct.micros.util.GetCustClass.main(GetCustClass.java:39)
```

I have tried System.load(absoulte path) and System.loadLibrary(sofilename). Both are giving the same error. When i copy this so file into usr/lib/jvm package, it is working..

can anyone help how to get this solved using Java. i'm running on linux box.

Comment: Can any one help me on this..!!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the library is on your path, but it can't be loaded for some other reason.

A trick I've used to debug problems like this is to run java -Xrunsofilename

-Xrun is the JVM option to load JVMPI libraries (the old profiling interface). If it succeeds, it will load the library and complain that it's not an agent library. But if it fails (hopefully!) it will print an error message. This is usually a more descriptive error message than what you get from the UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: I have tried this.. but it is giving
"Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find JVM_OnLoad or Agent_OnLoad function in the library:" .. is there any other solution for this?

Comment: That means that your library is OK. The problem must be elsewhere. Assuming you're on Linux, try running Java under strace (probably strace -f) and redirect stderr to a log. Then search the log for references to your library. This will let you see where the JVM is looking for the library. Is it looking where you expect? Are there any unexpected error codes in the trace?